# android:layout_anchor did not work properly in recyclerview'item .

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

[image: App Image]

**What is the issue?**

: In above picture , you can see 3rd item where the floating icon or view doesn't align properly as you can see in other items .

:Every time I open this screen ,some item's anchor view does not align properly.

**What I did?**

I implemented the Recycler with GridLayout manager .

```
//setting Grid layout
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, ROW_COUNT, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

and custom adapter.

**Item Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_image"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/service_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/COLOR.teal_green"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <mychatapplication.view.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/service_topic_title"
                style="@style/customCommonFont_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="Android tutorial text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <mychatapplication.view.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/service_topic_author"
                style="@style/customCommonFont_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="Jugal kishor joshi"
                android:textColor="@color/color_background_chat_text_view"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />

            <mychatapplication.view.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/service_topic_interest"
                style="@style/customCommonFont_regular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:text="Follow"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_profile_image_dummy"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/service_description"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user_profile_image_dummy"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/service_description"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"

    />
```

to include `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"`